# Change a field on change another field using django-autocomplete-light

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-forms, django-views

Basically I want to change value of company id and company name if your company field is changed. 
[image: img]
Here I have used [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) for your company field. Code for this form:

```
class PartnerAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
company_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'disabled': ''}), required=False)
company_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'disabled': ''}), required=False)


class Meta:
    model = CompanyCompanyMap
    fields = ('your_company',)
    widgets = {
        'your_company': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='url_company_autocomplete',
                                                  attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                         'data-placeholder': 'Type for getting available companies'})
    }
```

Code for autocomplete view of your company field:

```
class CompanyAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = CompanyAccess(self.request).get_non_partners()
    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(company_name__istartswith=self.q)
    return qs
```

And code for template of this form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="." method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% for f in form %}
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_{{ f.name }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ f.label|capfirst }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    {{ f }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}


            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">
                        Add Company as Friend
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- /.table-responsive -->
        </form>
```

Is there any way to change it using js or other mechanism?